# kTechlab in Ubuntu18.04

Tags: git, installation, ubuntu-18.04

I have a problem installing package kTechlab.

I tried to install kTechlab in Ubuntu18.04

```
sudo apt-get install git kdelibs5-dev kdevplatform-dev qt4-dev-tools cmake libglib2.0-dev
mkdir git-ktechlab && cd git-ktechlab
git clone git://github.com/ktechlab/ktechlab.git
cd ktechlab
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debugfull -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/
make
sudo make install
kbuildsycoca4 &> /dev/null
update-mime-database /usr/share/mime

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone git://github.com/ktechlab/ktechlab.git
```

Make sure the git clone step has succeed: I would use an HTTPS URL, not a `git://` one

```
git clone https://github.com/ktechlab/ktechlab.git
```